# Find nearest airport using lat long

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to find out nearest airport code using latitude and longitude.
I find URL which give me nearest airport:

http://airports.pidgets.com/v1/airports?near=40.1584,-74.9732

but problem is that this URL give 8 airports codes.
How can i find out nearest airport within this 8 airports code.

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `<dist>` is included, and appears to be in ascending order. So: take the first.

If you don't trust it, [compute the great arc distance](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) ;p

Comment: I am really sorry.. Didn't notice :)

Answer (score 3):

The resulting XML gives you a `<dist>` node which appears to give you the distance. So just take the one with the lowest `<dist>` value (seems to be ordered, so take the first).

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the distance node returned from the xml?

Comment: Please try to avoid sarcastic/unconstructive questions as answers. Much better to politely explain that there is a distance node that the OP may have missed.